# Passing a scalar reference in Perl

Tags: perl, reference, arguments, scalar

I know that passing a scalar to a sub is actually passing the reference, but since I am new to perl I still did the following test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$i = 2;
subr(\$i);
sub subr{
    print $_[0]."\n";
    print $$_[0]."\n";
}
```

I thought the first line is going to print an address and the second line is going to give be back the number, but the second one is a blank line. I was pointed by someone one else to do this: `${$_[0]}` and it prints the number. But she didn't know the reason why without {} it is not working and why it is working with {}. So what has happened?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because your second print statement is equivalent to doing this...

```
my $x = $$_; print $x[0];
```

When what you want is

```
my $x = $_[0]; print $$x;
```

In other words, the de-referencing occurs before the array subscript is evaluated.

When you add those curl-wurlies, it tells perl how to interpret the expression as you want it; it will evaluate `$_[0]` first, and then de-reference to get the value.

Answer (score 8):

It's an order-of-evaluation thing.

```
  $$_[0] is evaluated as {$$_}[0]
```

This is the 0th element of the reference of the scalar variable $_. It's taking the reference first and then trying to find the 0th element of it.

```
  ${$_[0]}
```

This is a reference to the 0th element of the array @_. It's finding the 0th element first then taking a reference of that.

If you set `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your code you'll see plenty of warnings about undefined values from your first attempt.

Answer (score 3):

`$$_[0]` is like `$foo[0]`, only with $_ in place of the array name.  This means $_ is treated as an array reference, and the expression doesn't involve the scalar reference `$_[0]` at all.  `$_->[0]` is equivalent, using the alternate `->` syntax.  Syntax for dereferencing may seem arbitrary and hard to remember, but there is underlying sense and order; a very good presentation of it is at http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass a reference to `$i`. The notation `$_[0]` is an *alias* for `$i` when you invoke it as `subr( $i )`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 2;

sub subr{ $_[0]++ } # messing with exactly what was passed first
my $i=2;
is( $i, 2, q[$i == 2] );
subr($i);
is( $i, 3, q[$i == 3] );
```

Another example is this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 6;
use Test::Exception;

sub subr{ $_[0]++ }
my $i=2;
is( $i, 2, q[$i == 2] );
subr($i);
is( $i, 3, q[$i == 3] );

sub subr2 { $_[0] .= 'x'; }
dies_ok { subr2( 'lit' ); } 'subr2 *dies* trying to modify a literal';
lives_ok { 
    my $s = 'lit';
    subr2( $s );
    is( $s, 'litx', q[$s eq 'litx'] );
    subr2(( my $s2 = 'lit' ));
    is( $s2, 'litx', q[$s2 eq 'litx'] );
} 'subr2 lives with heap variables';
```

Output:

```
ok 1 - $i == 2
ok 2 - $i == 3
ok 3 - subr2 *dies* trying to modify a literal
ok 4 - $s eq 'litx'
ok 5 - $s2 eq 'litx'
ok 6 - subr2 lives with heap variables
1..6
```